# Windows 8 App with Share contract only

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to create an app that "only" shows while using Share charm? I do not want the fullscreen app to be opened via live tile as there is no content to be displayed. I want it to be displayed only through Share charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible for an app to be shown only as a Share target.  All Windows Store apps have a tile on the Start Screen that can be used to launch the app.

Comment: in addition, an app that only services to be a share target will be rejected -- or so i heard from someone who submitted an application that was only a share target.