# Windows 8 pure live tile app possible?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to make a pure live tile app in Windows 8? That is, the only purpose of the app is displaying information on the tile, and it will do nothing when clicking on?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13504624/1656796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an app that is **only** a live tile is not possible.  When a user clicks/taps on a live tile, the associated Windows Store App will be launched.

Comment: Right. Having said that, nothing is to stop the developer from presenting the user with a "this app does nothing but update the live tile" if their use case demanded it. Then again, store certification will likely be rejected if the value of the app is perceived as zero.